# Why assigning characters to C++ string results in string having 0 length?

Tags: c++, string

I manually assigned characters from a string to another array of string. But why it results in having 0 length and cannot be directly printed? although the characters in the string can be printed by iterating.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string domain[100],text="google";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        domain[0][i] = text[i];
    }
    for(int k=0;k<6;k++){
        cout<<domain[0][k];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"String length: "<<domain[0].length()<<endl;
    cout<<"Output string directly from array : "<<domain[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
google
String length: 0
Output string directly from array :
```

Comment: Do you really mean to make an array of 100 `std::string`s?

Comment: @TartanLlama yes, for competitive programming questions purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing

```
 string domain[100]
```

you create an array of 100 empty strings then you try to access string characters by using `[]` operator, but the string has no characters, so setting them won't work. You shouldn't even try to access them this way. It causes Undefined Behavior.

EDIT.

In this line:

```
domain[0][i] = text[i];
```

you try to set the i-th character of the first string. But how many characters this string has? None.

It would be the same as if you'd try something like this:

```
domain[0] = "abc";
```

Then you can access `domain[0][0]` but can't access `domain[0][3]` because it has only 3 characters. Try to think of it as of an array. You cannot set 10-th element if the array has only 5 elements.

Comment: I don't understand. can you please explain more? since domain[0][0] domain[0][1] ... domain[0][5] each has a character. what is the difference between printing it with cout<<domain[0]? shouldn't it be printed as 1 string ?

Comment: @user3411184 `domain[0]` is empty, so `domain[0][0]` isn't valid.

Comment: The best solution is to get an [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read it.

Comment: oh I see, the last edited post make me understand. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
string domain[100];
```

You now have an array of 100 *empty* `string` objects.

(Why? You are only ever *using* the first one...)

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    domain[0][i] = text[i];
}
```

On first iteration, [`string::operator[]` will return a reference to `CharT()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) (the null character). Modifying that character is undefined behaviour. (Since C++11; earlier versions would invoke undefined behaviour at the `operator[]` already.)

Note that, in C++, the null character is not really a part of the string. This is different from C's `char[]`.

So your modifying the null character was undefined behaviour and did not actually add a character to the string object. On second iteration, there *still* is no character in the string, so `domain[0][1]` is an out-of-bounds access (which is also undefined behaviour).

You are probably looking for [`string::operator+=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) or [`string::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)...

---

Unrelated:

```
#include <string.h>
```

That's the wrong header. C++ strings are in `<strings>`, `<string.h>` is the now-deprecated way of including the **C** string header (the one with `strcpy()` et al.). If you actually *want* that, include `<cstring>`, which introduces the names from `<string.h>` in the `std::` namespace.

Comment: On first iteration, string::operator[] will return a reference to CharT() (the null character). Does it depend on implementation?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Not really, it's in the standard definition. See the link. Before C++11, the `operator[]` call would be UB even on the first iteration, since `domain[0]` is not `const`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I quite understand more from the other answer's explanation. anyway I'll try the push_back() thanks!

Comment: @DevSolar Could you tell me the definition's position in standard?

Comment: @songyuanyao: No, I don't have the C++ standard available. I am relying on the linked documentation.